# Why are commands executed in backquotes giving me different results when done in as script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that I mean to be run from cron that ensures that a daemon that I wrote is working.  The contents of the script file are similar to the following:

```
daemon_pid=`ps -A | grep -c fsdaemon`
echo "daemon_pid: " $daemon_pid
if [ $daemon_pid -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "restarting fsdaemon"
   /etc/init.d/fsdaemon start
fi
```

When I execute this script from the command prompt, the line that echoes the value of $daemon_pid is reporting a value of 2.  This value is two regardless of whether my daemon is running or not.  If, however, I execute the command with back quotes and then examine the $daemon_pid variable, the value of $daemon_pid is now one.  I have also tried single stepping through the script using bashdb and, when I examine the variables using that tool, they are what they should be.

My question therefore is: why is there a difference in the behaviour between when the script is executed by the shell versus when the commands in the script are executed manually?  I'm sure that there is something very fundamental that I am missing.

Comment: Just to check the obvious: the name of the script file doesn't include `fsdaemon`, does it?

Comment: As a matter of fact, the name of the script file is "check-fsdaemon".  That, perhaps, accounts for one of the counts (I am seeing two).  Is the other from the command line for grep?

Comment: also, there is `fsdaemon` in argument list of `grep` process. You can verify it without `-c`.

Comment: @Jon: yep, that's more or less it. I will elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very likely encountering the `grep` as part of the 'answer' from `ps`.

To help fully understand what is happening, turn off the `-c` option, to see what data is being returned from just `ps -A | grep fsdameon`.

To solve the issue, some systems have a p(rocess)grep (`pgrep`). That will work, OR

```
ps -A | grep -v grep | grep -c fsdaemon
```

Is a common idiom you will see, but at the expense of another process.

The cleanest solution is,

```
ps -A | grep -c '[f]sdaemon'
```

The regular expression syntax should work with all greps, on all systems.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I really like the pgrep command and it is supported under debian 5.  Thanks.

Comment: Based on my tests, it seems like `grep` is finding the subprocess spawned by the backquotes - it's not actually finding itself, because `ps -A` doesn't list command-line arguments.

Comment: Thanks for that insight. I usually use `ps -ef` or `ps auexww`, but left `ps -A` as part of my answer becuase that was the OPs usage.  Good luck to all.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that grep itself shows up... Try running this command with anything after grep -c:

```
eple:~ erik$ ps -a | grep -c asdfladsf
1
eple:~ erik$ ps -a | grep -c gooblygoolbygookeydookey
1
eple:~ erik$
```

What does `ps -a | grep fsdaemon` return? Just look at the processes actually listed... :)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is Linux, why not try the [pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep)? This saves you a pipe, and you don't end up with grep reporting back the daemon script itself running.

Answer (score 1):

Aany process with arguments including that name will add to the count - grep, and your script.

`ps`ing for a process isn't really reliable, you should use a lock file.

Answer (score 0):

As several people have pointed out already, your process count is inflated because `ps | grep` detects (1) the script itself and (2) the subprocess created by the backquotes, which inherits the name of the main script. So an easy solution is to change the name of the script to something that doesn't include the name you're looking for. But you can do better.

The "best-practice" solution that I would suggest is to use the facilities provided by your operating system. It's not uncommon for an init script to create a PID file as part of the process of starting your daemon; in other words, instead of just running the daemon itself, you use a wrapper script that starts the daemon and then writes the process ID to a file somewhere. If `start-stop-daemon` exists on your system (and I think it's fairly common these days), you can use that like so:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background \
     --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/fsdaemon.pid -- /usr/bin/fsdaemon
```

(obviously replace the path `/usr/bin/fsdaemon` as appropriate) to start it, and then

```
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile /var/run/fsdaemon.pid
```

to stop it. `start-stop-daemon` has other options that might be useful to you, which you can investigate by reading the man page.

If you don't have access to `start-stop-daemon`, you can write a wrapper script to do basically the same thing, something like this to start:

```
echo "$$" > /var/run/fsdaemon.pid
exec /usr/bin/fsdaemon
```

and this to stop:

```
kill $(< /var/run/fsdaemon/pid)
rm /var/run/fsdaemon.pid
```

(this is pretty crude, of course, but it should normally work).

Anyway, once you have the setup to generate a PID file, whether by using `start-stop-daemon` or not, you can update your check script to this:

```
daemon_pid=`ps --no-headers --pid $(< /var/run/fsdaemon.pid) | wc -l`
if [ $daemon_pid -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "restarting fsdaemon"
    /etc/init.d/fsdaemon restart
fi
```

(one would think there would be a concise command to check whether a given PID is running, but I don't know it).

If you don't want to (or can't) create a PID file, I would at least suggest `pgrep` instead of `ps | grep`, since `pgrep` will search directly for a process by name and won't find anything that just happens to include the same string.

```
daemon_pid=`pgrep -x -c fsdaemon`
if [ $daemon_pid -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "restarting fsdaemon"
    /etc/init.d/fsdaemon restart
fi
```

The `-x` means "match exactly", and `-c` works as with `grep`.

By the way, it seems a bit misleading to name your variable `daemon_pid` when it is actually a count.